# LWC: How do we attach an onfocus event to an input-field

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I'm trying to replicate a very simple functionality of copying a value in a `lightning-input-field` from another field `onfocus`.

Visualize something of a grid, where I would like to be able to Copy value of a field from top row onto the field that has the focus.

**LWC Component**:

```
<template>
    <div class="app slds-p-around_x-large">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" class="quickForm1 slds-p-bottom_small">
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId"></lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" class="quickForm2 slds-p-bottom_small">
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field name="fname" field-name="FirstName" onfocus={handleInputFocus}></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field name="lname" field-name="LastName" onfocus={handleInputFocus}></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field name="acc" field-name="AccountId" onfocus={handleInputFocus}></lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS Code:**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    handleInputFocus(event) {
        console.log('onfocus fired', event.target.name);
    }

}
```

I could not find any `onfocus` event on `lightning-input-field`, is there a way I can make this work?

In above code snippet, the `onfocus` event does not fire at all, while I get no error in deploying the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the tab-index property to 0 to make the element handle onfocus like this

```
<lightning-input-field  tabindex="0" onfocus={handleInputFocus} name="fname" field-name="FirstName" ></lightning-input-field>
```

JS

```
handleInputFocus(event) {
        console.log('onfocus fired');
        console.log(event.target.name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations with  lightning-input-field focus event.

1. only TAB key triggers the focus
2. the focus actually happens on the whole DOM of input-field, meaning the focus is not actually on the input box but one step above in the DOM tree
3. it won't trigger by mouse ( as an alternate you could use onclick event)

So the quick hack to make it work is to use standard [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event) event on lightning-input-field. It works exactly the way like lightning-input focus event. I know it is not documented on SF [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification) but these are standard events that are supported by modern browsers.

```
<lightning-input-field onfocusin={handleFocus} name="fname" field-name="FirstName" ></lightning-input-field>
```